# Reactive support for publishing to google pubsub topic

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, google-cloud-pubsub

It seems like PubSubReactiveFactory only supports polling but not publishing.

I'm not sure about this one, but I'm worried using the normal PubSubTemplate might have negative consequences to the application's performance as it doesn't use Schedulers but Executors instead, potentially leading to more threads than desired running in the application. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not an expert on the matter.

Anyway, could someone clarify me if this is a potential problem and are there plans to support a reactive publishing or, otherwise, if PubSubTemplate is safe to use on a reactive stack?

Answer (score 3):

`PubSubTemplate` publish methods are asynchronous, and so are safe to use in a reactive app in the sense of "safe" that they won't lock up your limited pool of processor-bound threads.

Having fewer thread pools is a good goal in itself because it lets Project Reactor more efficiently allocate work. The publisher thread pool is useful, though -- it manages async sending of messages in batches. It uses 4 threads by default, which you can customize with `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.publisher.executor-threads`.

We've originally created `PubSubReactiveFactory` to provide idiomatic reactive stream support with backpressure, as the streaming pull, while efficient, did not allow for message-level backpressure. It would not add a lot of value to implement reactive publishing, as it would use the same `PubSubTemplate` publish methods, get a `CompletableFuture` out of the Spring `ListenableFuture` and turn that into a `Mono` of the `String` message ID.

Comment: Thanks for replying Elena. I definitely agree with the fewer thread pools (and fewer threads) point. 
The bit I struggle to understand is why do we want to use a separate thread pool for publishing. I'm not concerned about the efficiency of the publishing process itself (you made that part clear), but about not reusing the same threads we are using for the rest of the I/O operations. 
Is it because of some advantage regarding the handling of messages in batches?

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't thinking of a wrapper around the `PubSubTemplate` that blindly transforms the returned `Future`  into a `Mono`, but on a different implementation using the same thread pool created via `Schedulers` instead. My feeling is that, otherwise, we are allocating 4 extra threads that won't be useful anywhere else. But again, I might be missing the point here if that dedicated thread pool offers some extra value the default reactive I/O ones can't

Comment: For a reactive application, the code that's not reactive-aware (even if it is asynchronous)  is effectively legacy code. Spring Cloud GCP integrations are built on top of client libraries, which are not reactive and so use their own thread pools for all functionality.

Comment: By the way, in addition to the 4 default publisher threads, you'll also have gRPC and GAX threads... You may find this helpful to reduce the overall number of extra threads if all you use is publish: https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/issues/27

Comment: "Spring Cloud GCP integrations are built on top of client libraries, which are not reactive and so use their own thread pools for all functionality"

I understand that applies also to `PubSubReactiveFactory` regardless of the backpressure support, as it also relies on a non reactive-aware library.

Comment: No. Asynchronous could be due to parallel threads running on each message push. This creates a lot of threads and memory usage. Reactive Streams is about asynchronity without multiple threads.